# fuzzy matching two strings uring r

Tags: r, text, match, fuzzy

I have two vectors, each of which includes a series of strings. For example,

```
V1=c("pen", "document folder", "warn")
V2=c("pens", "copy folder", "warning")
```

I need to find which two are matched the best. I directly use levenshtein distance. But it is not good enough. In my case, pen and pens should mean the same. document folder and copy folder are probably the same thing. warn and warning are actually the same. I am trying to use the packages like tm. But I am not very sure which functions are suitable for doing this. Can anyone tell me about this?

Comment: You need to look at `stringdist`.

Comment: probably need to make a custom dictionary of sorts. [This example using wordnet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512472/extracting-synonymous-terms-from-wordnet-using-synonym) may be helpful

Comment: Read up on Levenshtein distance. It's basically - how many "single move" changes need to be made to match strings. And best matching would be minimizing this value. `?adist`

Answer (score 3):

In my experience the cosine match is a good one for such kind of a jobs:

```
V1 <- c("pen", "document folder", "warn")
V2 <- c("copy folder", "warning", "pens")   
result <- sapply(V1, function(x) stringdist(x, V2, method = 'cosine', q = 1))
rownames(result) <- V2
result
                  pen document folder      warn
copy folder 0.6797437       0.2132042 0.8613250
warning     0.6150998       0.7817821 0.1666667
pens        0.1339746       0.6726732 0.7500000
```

You have to define a cut off when the distance is close enough, how lower the distance how better they match. You can also play with the Q parameter which says how many letters combinations should be compared to each other. For example:

```
result <- sapply(V1, function(x) stringdist(x, V2, method = 'cosine', q = 3))
rownames(result) <- V2
result
                  pen document folder      warn
copy folder 1.0000000       0.5377498 1.0000000
warning     1.0000000       1.0000000 0.3675445
pens        0.2928932       1.0000000 1.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of you! I will try these methods. Just one thing I am not sure: My strings are actually much more complex than this example. A string could be like "Tuesday KFC warnings pens document folder 13 * 15 two of them". It means there are some unuseful sub strings and some signs in it. I am afraid that in this case, directly using those distance function is not very appropriate. So I think about using tm package first for pre-processing? Any suggestions?

Comment: The tm package is a really good one for pre processing. This link could maybe help you in preprocessing the data: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/31867_8236987cf0a8444e962ccd2aec46d9c3.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's wiki for [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It measures how many delete/change/insert actions need to be taken to transform strings. And one of approaches for fuzzy matching is minimizing this value.

Here's an example. I shuffled up order a bit, to make it less boring:

```
V1 <- c("pen", "document folder", "warn")
V2 <- c("copy folder", "warning", "pens")

apply(adist(x = V1, y = V2), 1, which.min)
[1] 3 1 2
```

Output means, which positions of V2 correspond to closest transformation of V1, in order of V1.

```
data.frame(string_to_match = V1, 
           closest_match = V2[apply(adist(x = V1, y = V2), 1, which.min)])
  string_to_match closest_match
1             pen          pens
2 document folder   copy folder
3            warn       warning
```